# How to sum values in a loop with conditions in Xslt

Tags: xslt, sum, conditional-statements, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I need help with something, I need transform this file, but i have this condition: when the QTY > 0 and QTY < 1, I should replace for 1 and finally sum all values

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<DellistDocument>
  <DELLIST>
    <QTY>3.50</QTY>
  </DELLIST>
  <DELLIST>
    <QTY>0.002</QTY>
  </DELLIST>
  <DELLIST>
    <QTY>0.80</QTY>
  </DELLIST>
</DellistDocument>
```

I need loop for every QTY and change the values if is necessary in the transform map, I need to do a sum like this:

```
<QTY>3.50</QTY> ----> value = 3.50
<QTY>0.002</QTY> ----> value = 1
<QTY>0.80</QTY> ----> value = 1

Total Sum = 5.50
```

I try with this, but really I'm stuck about how to do this :

```
<xsl:variable name="QTYItem">
  <xsl:for-each select="$Dellist">
    <xsl:variable name="QTYCountItemValue" select="number(normalize-space(QTY/text()))" />
    <xsl:variable name="QTYItemValidateValue">
    
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$QTYCountItemValue &gt; 0 and $QTYCountItemValue &lt; 1">
              <xsl:value-of select="number(1)" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="number($QTYCountItemValue)" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <xsl:value-of select="sum($QTYItemValidateValue)" />
  </xsl:for-each>
  
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="$QTYItem" />
```

**The result of this is : 3.5011** , This is putting the loop values, but I need to sum all, how can I do this? I expect as a result 5.50

**I'm working in XSLT 3.0**

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to loop in order to sum values. Here you could do simply:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:template match="/DellistDocument">
    <output>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(DELLIST/(if (number(QTY) gt 0 and number(QTY) lt 1) then 1 else number(QTY)))"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmCzsX/1

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way this could be done.
There might be easier ways...

Not sure what your required output is, but you can modify the output format if required.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:my="http://www.my.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs my"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="DellistDocument">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <TOTAL><xsl:value-of select="my:total(DELLIST[1],0)"/></TOTAL>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="QTY[number(.)&gt;0 and number(.)&lt;1]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- Recursive function to round the numbers and add them -->
  <xsl:function name="my:total" as="xs:double">
    <xsl:param name="currDELLIST"/>
    <xsl:param name="total"/>
    <xsl:variable name="currQTY" select="($currDELLIST/QTY)[1]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="round" select="if($currQTY&gt;0 and $currQTY&lt;1) then 1 else $currQTY"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="if($currDELLIST/following-sibling::DELLIST) 
                            then my:total($currDELLIST/following-sibling::DELLIST, $round+$total) 
                            else $round+$total"/>
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxDjimT